# Save variable to global var during function call

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, callback

I have the following function to parse an Array and to return only specific items:

```
function fetchLogs(logs) {
    var arr = logs.value;
    var res = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
        if (b.level === 'INFO') {
            a.push(b.message.split(" ").pop().replace(/"/g, ""))
        }
        return a;
    }, []);
    console.log("function", res);
    return res; // Is this return right?
}
```

The use of the function is to get browser logs returned (Browser A and Browser B) and to check if the logs matches.

So my test looks like that

```
it('should return logs from browser B', function(done) {
    browserB
      .log('browser')
      .then(function(logs) {
        fetchLogs(logs);
        done();
      })
    .catch(function(e) {
      done(e);
    })
});
```

And at the end I want to compare those Arrays

```
it('should compare browser logs', function() {
    expect(logsA).to.have.all.members(logsB);
});
```

**Question here:**

How can I save the variable *res* from the function to my previously declared global variable *logsB* inside when I call the *fetchLogs(logs)* function? Do I need a callback or Promise here?

Is also the function properly done with the return?

Comment: if you use `var fetchResult = fetchLogs();` then you'll have the logs in a var you can do whatever with. (like set a global, or use it as a parameter for a function that triggers the test. So your return is correct if this is actually what you're trying to do. Looking at the code, you probably want two variables logsA and logsB that are in the same scope as the functions, so those functions can see logsA and logsB.

Comment: @Shilly Works like a charm and I have no idea why I did not thought about that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution that worked for me:

```
var fetchResult = fetchLogs();
```